# Samsung S5 screen turning on and off when plugged in to charge

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have a Samsung S5 & when I plug the phone in to charge every few seconds my screen lights up then turns off.  If I have my sound on it play a notification every-time the screen turns on and off.

Any advice on how I can stop this - it's makn me loco :-)!!!

ASM

Comment: This could be due to a bad USB cable, have you tried another cable to see if it is doing the same thing?

Comment: Well I feel like an idiot :-)!  That totally worked Sjharrison - thank you so much!

Comment: We've all been there! had so many issues myself with my old S3 and data cables, I've recently got a S5 and only using official cables now just to avoid any issues

Comment: @Sjharrison, you should turn your comment into an answer so that ASM can accept it and give you reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem - plugged the Samsung cable into a dual charger with higher current capability (my wife left her charger at the cabin) and the phone quit complaining.

An intelligent design decision - have the phone use more power to complain about not enough power during charging...

Answer (score 0):

Try an alternative cable, some non official (cheaper) leads can break for easier than others and cause the phone not to charge properly, hence why your phone is making a sound and switching the screen on and off

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but none of the above solutions worked .

What did the trick is using a pointed wooden toothpick. See if the charging port is in the center and not bent. If you find the port is bent, then straighten it using the wooden toothpick carefully.Furthermore, verify that the charging contacts are clean.